# The "Does this answer your question?" banner persists. Why?

Tags: bug, information-display, duplicate-suggestions

I had a suggested duplicate on a site-meta post, and the yes/no banner came up.

I chose "no" and a popup came up recommending editing the post.

I did so, by clicking on the popup's edit button, and, on reopening my post, the banner is still there (no additional close votes were applied).

Why does it persist? I already answered no and made the appropriate edit.

> [image]

Comment: The large number of duplicates on this subject may suggest that the dialog could be improved.